# Restricting AWS cloud resources & user using IAM

Tags: amazon-web-services, security, amazon-iam

I want to implement Security in AWS Cloud using IAM like below:

```
1. Restricting Region(Possible)
2. Restricting Particular Service(EC2/RDS/VPC)(Possible)
3. Restricting IAM user(Disabled other IAM user resources)(Not Sure)
4. Deleting IAM user should delete AWS Resources created by this user.(Not Sure)
```

I came across Cloud Training site called `Qwiklabs` where they restrict exactly what I need.

I already tried and done first two restrictions(Region and Services).
Now I'm not sure for remaining 3rd and 4th.

Can anyone suggest me how to implement this scenario?

Answer (score 0):

Ad 3. - Can You elaborate?
In Qwiklabs Your labs are created on separate AWS account - no other users are there.

Ad. 4 - You will have to force all users to use CloudFormation do provision resources or develop a process (Lambda/Step function) triggered by delete user action

Comment: 3:- Is Qwiklabs creating separate account for each training?

Comment: According to my knowledge, yes. Not sure account/training or account/lab.
I'll check it on Monday :)

Answer (score 0):

4.Deleting IAM user should delete AWS Resources created by the user - You can use AWS Cloudtrail/AWS Lambda for that.

AWS Lambda:

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/events/RunLambdaSchedule.html

You can create a Lambda function which triggers as soon as the user logs in. The first Lambda function should create another Lambda Function with the scheduled events associated.

The second Lambda Function contains the specific user's information, instructions for deleting the resources created by the specific user and the instructions to delete the scheduled event.

With AWS CloudTrail:

By using the below sample command you can get the list of actions performed by the user.

```
aws cloudtrail lookup-events --lookup-attributes AttributeKey=username,AttributeValue=user@example.com
```

Once you have that you can delete them.